# LEFT JOIN does not return all the records from the left side table

Tags: mysql, sql, join, left-join, where-clause

```
SELECT d.mt_code,
       d.dep_name,
       d.service_name,
       COUNT(*)
FROM DepartmentService AS d
LEFT JOIN tbl_outgoing AS t ON d.mt_code = t.depCode
WHERE d.service_type = 'MT'
  AND t.smsc = "mobitelMT"
  AND t.sendDate BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-02'
GROUP BY d.mt_code
```

`DepartmentService` table has details about departments that offer services. `tbl_outgoing` table contains all the transactions happened for a particular service which are done by customers. In the `WHERE` clause two cafeterias should be fulfilled which are `service_type = 'MT' and  smsc = "newMT"`. I want to get a report which shows all the departments with the transactions for a given period. I have used a `LEFT JOIN` because I want to get all the departments. SQL works fine and get the result I want except,

When there are no transactions for a particular service for a particular period, The department is also ignored. What I want to do is show the department in the resultset and COUNT(*) column to be 0.

How can I do that?

Comment: please provide some sample data and required output

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem could be that you are filtering on the joined table using the where condition which will filter also the department services which don"t have a match in the join, move the filtering in the join and leave only the filters on `d` in the where clause:

```
SELECT d.mt_code,
   d.dep_name,
   d.service_name,
   COUNT(t.id)
FROM DepartmentService AS d
LEFT JOIN tbl_outgoing AS t 
  ON d.mt_code = t.depCode 
    AND t.smsc = "mobitelMT"
    AND t.sendDate BETWEEN '2014-07-01' AND '2014-07-02'
WHERE d.service_type = 'MT'
GROUP BY d.mt_code
```

---

To explain why this happens I'll walk you through what happens with your query and with my query, as dataset I'll use this:

```
states
 ____ _________ 
| id | state   |
|  1 | Germany |
|  2 | Italy   |
|  3 | Sweden  |
|____|_________|

cities

 ____ ________ ___________ ____________
| id | city   | state_fk  | population |
|  1 | Berlin |        1  |         10 |
|  2 | Milan  |        2  |          5 |
|____|________|___________|____________|
```

First I'll go through your query.

```
SELECT s.id, s.state, c.population, c.city
FROM states s
LEFT JOIN cities c
ON c.state_fk = s.id
WHERE c.population < 10
```

So le't go step by step, you select the three states, left join with cities ending up with:

```
 ____ _________ ____________ ________
| id | state   | population | city   |
|  1 | Germany |         10 | Berlin |
|  2 | Italy   |          5 | Milan  |
|  3 | Sweden  |       NULL | NULL   |
|____|_________|____________|________|
```

The you filter the population using `WHERE c.population < 10`, at this point your left with this:

```
 ____ _________ ____________ ________
| id | state   | population | city   |
|  2 | Italy   |          5 | Milan  |
|____|_________|____________|________|
```

You loose Germany because Berlin population was 10 **but you lost also Sweden** which had NULL, if you wanted to keep the nulls you should have specified it in the query:

```
WHERE (c.population < 10 OR IS NULL c.population)
```

Which returns:

```
 ____ _________ ____________ ________
| id | state   | population | city   |
|  2 | Italy   |          5 | Milan  |
|  3 | Sweden  |       NULL | NULL   |
|____|_________|____________|________|
```

---

Now my query:

```
SELECT s.id, s.state, c.population, c.city
FROM states s
LEFT JOIN cities c
ON c.state_fk = s.id
  AND c.population < 10
```

Before joining the two, we filter the table cities (using the `AND c.population < 10` condition after the `ON`), what remains is:

```
 ____ ________ ___________ ____________
| id | city   | state_fk  | population |
|  2 | Milan  |        2  |          5 |
|____|________|___________|____________|
```

Because Milan is the only city with population minor than 10, **now** we can join the two tables:

```
 ____ _________ ____________ ________
| id | state   | population | city   |
|  1 | Germany |       NULL | NULL   |
|  2 | Italy   |          5 | Milan  |
|  3 | Sweden  |       NULL | NULL   |
|____|_________|____________|________|
```

As you can see the data from the left table stays because the filtering condition was applied **only** to the cities table.

---

The result set changes depending on what you want to achieve, if for example you do want to filter Germany because Berlin has population minor than 10 and keep Sweden you should use the first approach adding the `IS NULL` condition, if you want to keep it instead, you should use the second approach and pre filter the table on the right of the left join.

Comment: +1 Yes, Exactly that's the problem. Can you explain the answer a bit more , so I can understand and accept it.

Comment: I made an edit, hope it was clear enough, if not I will edit again later, unfortunately I don't have much time right now.

Comment: Even there are no transactions the COUNT(*) is shown as 1 where it should be 0.

Comment: I'm not sure, could you try to `COUNT(d.id)`?

Comment: I still don't understand how does it make a different filtering on the WHERE and filtering on the JOIN ON. Can you please explain the different? How does it work?

Comment: @Dasun, please have some patience, I will edit my answer later (or tonight) and provide a better example.

Comment: +1. I think you should edit the `COUNT(t.id)` (instead of the `COUNT(*)`) into the answer.

Comment: And I think it should be `COUNT(t.id)` or `COUNT(t.depCode)`. But not `COUNT(d.id)`. @Dasun, have you checked which one changes the 1s to 0s?

Comment: Ah you are right, he wants to count the transactions, I was counting the departements...